# std::filesystem error: directory iterator cannot open directory: Not a directory

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project for school and having a problem using C++ std::filesystem while trying to iterate through a directory's files. I create a path object from a string passed into the command line (argv2 is "C:\cygwin64\home\landl\CS2341\cs2341_project_data.zip\cs2341_data"), then try to simply print out the filename of all the files in filepath:

```
        fs::path filepath = argv2;
        for (const auto& dirEntry: fs::directory_iterator(filepath)) {
            std::cout << dirEntry.path() << std::endl;
        }
```

But I get the following error when running the code:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: directory iterator cannot open directory: Not a directory [C:\cygwin64\home\landl\CS2341\cs2341_project_data.zip\cs2341_data]
```

I think I understand what the error is saying, that the given string is not a filepath that can be opened. I don't understand why though, because it's the full file path of a folder that contains the files I want to iterate over. Why does passing this string in not work? I saw similar examples that ran passing in a string in a similar way.

I couldn't find anything either that explained why this is happening, either in the std::filesystem documentation or on this website.
I'm totally new to using std::filesystem so I would appreciate any input. Thank you!

Comment: `filesystem` doesn't have the knowledge to unzip cs2341_project_data.zip to find the compressed folder.

Comment: The browsing through `.zip` files is a feature of the GUI file explorer. The filesystem does not do this.

Comment: Silly mistake on my part. Thank you!